# What is the best way to combine model results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm trying to combine two different models to one model so I could filter the results as one list.

Model:

```
    public partial class OverviewItems
{
    // Videos and Images combined for overview
    [NotMapped]
    public List<dynamic> Item { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult LoadItems(int skip = 0, int take = 4)
        {
            OverviewItems items = new OverviewItems();
            // get al the videos an images, order them by creaton date. Take onyly the latest videos/images combined.

        var images = db.Images.Where(i => i != null && i.Items != null && i.Items.Count() > 0).OrderByDescending(i => i.CreatedOn).Take(take).Skip(skip) as IEnumerable<object>;
        var videos = db.Videos.Where(v => v != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(v.Watch_id)).OrderByDescending(v => v.CreatedOn).Take(take).Skip(skip) as IEnumerable<object>;

        items.Item.Add(images);
        items.Item.Add(videos);

        // ViewBag.Items = images.Concat(videos);
        return PartialView("OverviewItems", items);
    }
```

The Videos and Images are entity framework classes with items.

```
    public partial class Videos : OverviewItems
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
```

The same for the Images model. but off course with different properties.

I have also tried an ViewBag but that dosn't work either because the videos and images are of an different type, even if i cast them to an dynamic.

What part did I miss? is there an easy solution to combine the two sets so I can filter/take/skip the items easly into one partial?

Comment: Create a view model with 2 properties from your collections

Comment: How? I would like to combine the results, not creating two different sets of items.

Comment: I would also do `db.Videos.Where(v => v != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(v.Watch_id)).OrderByDescending(v => v.CreatedOn).Take(take).Skip(skip).ToList();` as well. If you use generics rather than dynamics you'll find it easier as well.

Comment: ViewData["images"] = images;
ViewData["videos"] = videos;

Comment: What are the movie and image types?

Comment: How could you possibly create a view based on `dynamic` if they are different types. Use a view model. `public class MyViewModel { public IEnumerable<Image> Images { get; set; } public IEnumerable<Video> Videos { get; set; } }` and pass that to your view

Comment: Create a base class and derive from that to create your image and video items. Then cast accordingly where you need it.

Comment: See my updated question with my models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public abstract class OverviewItems
{
    public abstract string GetTitle();
}   

public class Videos : OverviewItems
{
    public string videoTitle { get; set; }
    public override string GetTitle()
    {
        return videoTitle;

    }
}

public class Images : OverviewItems
{
    public string imagesTitle { get; set; }
    public override string GetTitle()
    {
        return imagesTitle;

    }
}

 IList<OverviewItems> items = new List<OverviewItems>();

 var images = db.Images.Where(i => i != null && i.Items != null && i.Items.Count() > 0).OrderByDescending(i => i.CreatedOn).Take(take).Skip(skip).ToList();
 var videos = db.Videos.Where(v => v != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(v.Watch_id)).OrderByDescending(v => v.CreatedOn).Take(take).Skip(skip).ToList();

items.Add(images);
items.Add(videos);

var filtredItems = items.where(i=>i.GetTitle() == "SomeTitle");
```

Comment: How do you do the items.Add part? when I do this in my own code i've got errors. What cast sould I use?

Error:
Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection

Comment: I don't' think that you need to make a cast, look at update

Comment: Invalid arguments for the Add. when doing .FirstOrDefault inside the add it works but than breaks inside my PartislView (and only one item)

Comment: I really wondered that you have troubles with Add, because it works fine for me, please take a more details,

Comment: Thanks! creating the list again and checked my models. now it its working the way I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Concat" method

```
var images = db.Images.Where(i => i != null && i.Items != null && i.Items.Count() > 0).OrderByDescending(i => i.CreatedOn).Take(take).Skip(skip) as IEnumerable<object>;

var videos = db.Videos.Where(v => v != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(v.Watch_id)).OrderByDescending(v => v.CreatedOn).Take(take).Skip(skip) as IEnumerable<object>;

var combined = images.Concat(videos);
items.Item.Add(combined);
```

Comment: When I do this the following error is showing up:

Results View = 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'